# How to control experiment in labview from python on linux?

Tags: python, ubuntu, labview

I need to open labview experiment (.vi file) from python, pass parameters to it and start experiment. Everything should be done on ubuntu 20.4. I found out it can be done with tcp communication, but it's quite complicated, is there any easier way ? For example on windows you can do it very easily when you import win32com.client :

```
labview = \win32com.client.Dispatch("Labview.Application")
VI = labview.getvireference("Example.vi")
VI.setcontrolvalue('Period', 1.5)
VI.setcontrolvalue('file_path', "C:\\new.txt")

try:  # have to do this,otherwise: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
    VI.Run(False)  # False=wait until vi finishes, True=don't wait

except:
    print("Exception")
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [python_labview_automation package](https://github.com/ni/python_labview_automation). While I have not tested it myself it looks as if it does exactly what you want.

It only depends on Windows to start the actual LabView instance and run the server-side VI that is contained in the package. So you can either start LabView yourself or modify the package to know how to start LabView under linux.